# How to get the value in asyncfunction using node js?

Tags: node.js, async-await, node-modules

I tried to call function to return data to dict inside async function. but its not return data it returns async function how to get the data in async function can give me any solution.

**Sample .js**

```
function data()
{
    return "hai"
}

let dict = {sample:async () => {
    return (await data())
}}


console.log(await dict['sample'])
```

**Expected Output**

```
hai
```

**I got output**

```
[AsyncFunction: sample]
```

Comment: Change your `console.log(await dict['sample'])` to `console.log(await dict['sample']())`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code, `dict['sample']` is an async function.  If you want to get the value from that function, you have to call that async function which then returns a promise.  You can then use `.then()` or `await` on that promise to get the value from it.

And, your function `data()` is NOT an `async` function so you should not use `await` on it.

Breaking this into a few more steps to better understand it:

```
function data() {
    return "hai"
}

let dict = {
    sample: async () => {
        return data();
    }
};

let fn = dict['sample'];
fn().then(val => {
    console.log(val);
});
```

Or, if this was all inside an `async` function, you could use `await` instead of `.then()` to get the value.  So, if you want a one-liner for that:

```
console.log(await (dict['sample']()));
```

In either case, an `async` function always returns a promise (when you call that function) and the two ways you get the value out of a promise are with `.then()` or with `await`.

Answer (score 2):

That needs to be:

```
onsole.log(await (dict['sample']()))
```

Otherwise you're just returning the function itself, not invoking the function.